# getting object properties from a event handler function

Tags: javascript, function

why is the 'onClick=onClickRemove(items.objectID)' giving error items not defined:
The array List:

```
const list = [
{
title: 'React',
author: 'Jordan Walke',
objectID: 0,
},
{
title: 'Redux',
author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
objectID: 1,
},
]
```

the extracting function for map:  Here the onClickremove(items.objectID) is not getting the property from the items array?why please explain.

```
function extractProps(items){
    var x = "<div> <span>" +items.title+", </span> <span>"+items.author +
        "</span><span>
<button type='button' onClick='onClickRemove(items.objectID)'>Remove</button></span></div> "
return x;
}
```

"onClickRemove" Function:

```
  function onClickRemove(id){
        console.log(id)
    //     const updatedList = list.filter(isNotId = (item)=> item.objectID!==id);
    //     console.log(id);
    //    mapFilteredArray(updatedList);
    }
```

The main function:

```
   function myFunc(searchitem=''){

        document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = "";
        var y= list.filter( (item) => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchitem.toLowerCase())).map(extractProps).join("");;

    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = filteredList;
    }
    myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```js
const list = [
  { title: 'React',author: 'Jordan Walke',objectID: 0,},
  { title: 'Redux',author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',objectID: 1,}
]

function extractProps(items){
    var x = "<div> <span>" +items.title+", </span> <span>"+items.author +
        "</span><span><button type='button' onClick='onClickRemove("+items.objectID+")'>Remove</button></span></div> "
    return x;
}


function onClickRemove(id){
        console.log(id)
    //     const updatedList = list.filter(isNotId = (item)=> item.objectID!==id);
    //     console.log(id);
    //    mapFilteredArray(updatedList);
}


function myFunc(searchitem=''){
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = "";
    var filteredList= list.filter( (item) => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchitem.toLowerCase())).map(extractProps).join("");;
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = filteredList;
}

myFunc();
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

You inserted the `items.objectID` as a string right here `'onClickRemove(items.objectID)'` thus causing the problem. I extracted it and concatenated its actual value

Comment: that solved it thanks, and i also want to ask that how can i delete the list ?how can i re render the list?
function onClickRemove(id){
        console.log(id)
      const updatedList = list.filter(isNotId = (item)=> item.objectID!==id);
    console.log(id);
}

Comment: @OsamaSohail do you mean to delete an item from the list?

Comment: when the delete button is clicked the onClickRemove function is executed which removes that particular list,now i want the updated list to be shown in the div

Comment: just call `myFunc` inside `onClickRemove` after deleting an item. just as an advice: try react.

Comment: actually this is an example of react from book 'road to learn react' , i wanted to implement it in pure javascript